# google home device user id regenerating

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

i have a two google home device and one is working on apartment one and another is working on apartment two

the request from apartment one and apartment two are linked with my dialogflow so request is coming to my app by webhook fulfillment

i want to identify the request is coming from which apartment or Google home device, i used userId to identify but sometimes it changing dynamically either each request.

```
   'originalRequest': {
          'source': 'google', 'data': {
            'user': {
              'userId': '1529084528066', 'locale': 'en-US'
            }
    }
```

'userId': '1529084528066' is changing dynamically on conversation any help how to link the Google device to particular task

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you either do not have voice detection enabled on each device, or it is unable to match your voice to one of its configured voices. In this case, it treats the response as "anonymous" so generates a temporary userId.

Note also that [user IDs are deprecated](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info). If you need to track users between invocations, you might want to use [user storage](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info#migrating_to_webhook-generated_ids) to hold your own user ID.